# Type mismatch error: Cannot convert from Player to Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

How would I go about making multiple threads of an object?

I have a class with a constructor `Player(String, int, int)`. 
Now, in my main, I want to create multiple `Player` objects to use as threads.

I tried making an array of these objects

```
Thread[] player= new Thread[numberOfPlayers];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++)
    {
       player[i] = new Player("Default", 0, (i + 1));
    }
```

but get a 'Type mismatch error: Cannot convert from Player to Thread'.

I basically want to create these threads in a loop because every time the program runs, there will be a random number of players. The threads will need to access a list of information corresponding to the values given to each character (String, int, int) and update them one at a time. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would advise you not to use Character as a name for a class, since it is already the name of one in the java.lang.package, and is therefore imported everywhere in your code.

Comment: change it as `player[i] =new Thread( new Player("Default", 0, (i + 1)));`

Answer (score 3):

Unless `Character` is a subclass of `Thread`, you can't put `Character` objects into a `Thread[]`. This is true for all objects--you can't treat an object of one type (say, `B`) as though it were another type (say, `B`) unless [`B extends A`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

```
class A {
    // Empty base class
}

public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        A[] arrayOfAs= new A[1];
        arrayOfAs[0] = b; // Compile-time error! b is not an A object!
    }
}
```

vs.

```
public class B extends A { // B is now a subclass of A
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        A[] arrayOfAs= new A[1];
        arrayOfAs[0] = b; // Works just fine now
    }
}
```

---

Personally, it really doesn't sound like you actually need threads. Are you aware of [what the `Thread` class is for](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)? Why not just make the array out of what your objects actually are? Some other things as well: I'd rename `Character`, since that's already a class in the standard library. You'll also get a compile error if you try to name something `char`, because that identifier is reserved for the `char` primitive type.

```
Player[] players = new Player[numberOfPlayers];
```

Comment: @jsan, that's fine; just ignore the last part of the answer in that case. Your class still has to inherit from `Thread` if you're going to put it into a `Thread[]`.

Comment: @jsan Does the assignment explicitly say that the players have to be threads, or that they must execute in multiple threads? If they must execute in multiple thread I'd suggest you just make them implement Runnable, construct threads with new Thread(Player) and then just use thread.start.

Comment: @Luis From the assignment: "Each of our Players is represented by a thread. Each thread operates independently from the others. (i.e., it will be scheduled independently). That being said, the threads will have to share data in some fashion."

Answer (score 1):

I **think** what you are trying to do is something like this:

Create a set of `Player` class instances.  The Player class would have an `activate` method that would start a loop.  That loop would cause the player to move and do other things, then sleep, then repeat, endlessly.  Something like:

```
Player[] parray = new Player[nop];
for (int i = 0; i < nop; i++)  parray[i] = new Player( ... );
for (Player p : parray)  p.activate();
```

where activate looks like:

```
public void activate()  {
    new Thread( new Runnable()  {
        public void run()  {
            while (true)  {
                Player.this.x += xshift;
                Player.this.y += yshift;
                // Do other things.
                Thread.sleep( 500 );
            }
        }
    } ).start();
}
```

Note:  this code is hopelessly incomplete.  I'm just trying to hint at how it can be done.

Unless you're ready for a lot of really tough programming, you would do better to skip the "activate" method, put the run method directly in Player, and make your Players move with a loop like so:

```
while (true)  {
for (Player p : parry)  p.run();
// Do non-player stuff here.
}
```

Now you're in only one thread.  A lot less will go wrong, and when it does you'll be able to track it down.  (And I'm still just giving hints.  It'll be no small job to integrate that infinite loop with the UI.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `char` as an identifier because it is a reserved word. Just change your array name to `chars` our something.

Also your Character class will have to extend Thread in order to put it in a Thread array.

See also http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords